# Is Electric potential constant inside a conductor in all conditions?

Tags: potential, conductors

As electric field remains the zero inside the conductor so the potential at the surface should be the same as inside, but i came with  a situation which is as follows:  if a spherical conductor is placed inside (concentrically)  a conducting shell which has greater dimensions than that of the first conductor and a some charge is given to the smaller conductor
then no work should be done as the potential remains the same
however if we weld a metal conductor conducting the two spheres, then we notice that  the entire charge Q must be appear on the outer sphere by Gauss's law.  I'm not able to understand the two above contradicting statements.
Thanks.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/547484/why-is-there-electric-field-inside-conductor-in-between-shells-if-inner-shell-is

Comment: @green_32 - Hi. Welcome to SE. Just as a reminder, if an answer solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution you could accept it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the charged sphere has the same potential everywhere, but it's not true that the potential is the same as any other conductor. In particular, the concentric shell around the sphere will have a potential difference with respect to the sphere, which can be eliminated by connecting the metal conductor connecting the two. The work required for the charges to flow to the outer shell will be equal to the total energy stored in the electric field between the two conductors.

Comment: Can you please explain why there exists a potenital difference  between the two conductors? Let's say a test charge is kept at the centre of the sphere we bring to it to the surface of the outer sphere, since there exists no electric field inside either of the spheres,(both conductors) W=0, leading to V=0. what's incorrect in this?

Comment: Because there is a nonzero electric field in the space between them. Draw a Gaussian surface that encloses the inner sphere but no part of the shell. Since the sphere is charged, the normal component of the electric field on that surface is nonzero. The potential difference is then the line integral of that electric field from the sphere to the shell.

Comment: Then, after we weld  the metal conductor why does entire charge Q , appear on the surface of outer shell,  that would make the flux outside  the inner shell surface zero, leading to normal component of field to be zero as field distribution does not depend upon the area due to symmetry

Comment: All the charge $Q$ will flow to the outer shell once the conductors are welded together. The electric field between the two conductors will vanish, as you observed. The energy required to move the charges to the surface of the outer shell will be equal to the energy stored in the electric field between the shells, which is now gone.

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field#Energy_in_the_electric_field

Comment: but, why does the entire charge  need to flow out to make the potenital be  same between the surfaces under equlibrium conditions , upon solving we get Va = k(Q-x)/r1 =Kx/r2 =V2 where the V1 and V2 denote the potential at the surfaces of inner shell and outer shell respectively   here x does not come to be Q

Comment: Once the charges move to the surface of the outer shell, there is zero electric field everywhere in the conductors (by Gauss' law), and hence the conductors are equipotential ($V = \int \text{d}r ~E $)

Answer (score 1):

> As electric field remains the zero inside the conductor

That "inside" can be read in different ways.  If you mean inside the bulk conductor, it is correct.  If you mean in the interior portion of a hollow conductor, it may not be correct.

If you have two conducting shells, there will be zero field within the bulk metal of either shell, but there can be a field in the gap between the shells.  This will be the case if the interior shell is charged.

Comment: What's the reason behind the electric field not being zero in the gap between the shells, can we  prove this mathematically  ? And also, what about the electric current in steady conditions  due to drifting of electrons since they experience net force

Comment: Charge the interior shell.  Draw a gaussian envelope with that shell inside and the other shell outside.  As the envelope surrounds a non-zero charge, and the envelope is within the gap between the shells, there must exist a field also between the shells.

Comment: Your electric current comment sounds like a different question?  There's no current required at all in this question.

Comment: Sorry I meant, if we repeat the same activity replacing hollow one with solid, then there would be no charge flow from the inner to outer one right? As potenital should remain same

Comment: If there's a path across the gap, charges would move, so potential would not remain the same.

Comment: the charges would move till the time the two surfaces have the same potenital, so then why does entire charge Q move out to the surface after welding the conductor, shouldn't the inner surface should have Qr1/r1+r2 charge and outer one remaining, this makes the potenital same